# IIS 5.1 Not working on LAN

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have `IIS 5.1` installed on Windows XP.I have a ASP.NET web application deployed on it.
The application is only accessible on the `localhost` and not on the `LAN`.
Its available for `http://<my.ip>/Home.aspx` on my production system.

I think its a server configuration issue as I am not able to access the any of website on my LAN computers.

I have used the permissions wizard to change the setting to public in `IIS 5.1` .

I have disabled my  `firewall` and `ping` to the server is working fine.

Please help.

P.S : I am new to `IIS` and I have to use this version of `IIS 5.1` on windows XP.

Comment: Have you set up the IP bindings properly for the site?

Comment: What do you mean with _"Its available for http://<my.ip>/Home.aspx on my production system"_? Do you mean you can access the same machine on IP, but not on hostname? What _does_ happen if you access it by hostname? What happens if you access it by hostname from the machine itself?

Comment: Thank u so much for replying me..Yes...its works fine in my system both for ip address and the host name...but i am unable to access it from the host machine..

Comment: Hi Lloyd...can u please tel me what all bindings i have to set up??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed my OS.
IIS of windows XP does not work properly.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In inetmgr, right-click on your website, choose Properties, and on the Web site tab, set the IP address. It's probably set to 127.0.0.1 (localhost) now, you should set it to the IP address of the LAN card of your server. You can set the port here, too.

For example, if the server's LAN address is 10.232.171.245, and the port is 8080, then your IIS webserver will now bind to and wait for incoming HTTP connections at the socket 10.232.171.245:8080:

[image: Website Properties]

**=== UPDATE ===**

If the above is set, check Windows firewall settings:

1. In Control Panel, click on Windows Firewall
2. In the Windows Firewall dialog, choose the Exceptions tab and click on Add port...
3. In the Add Port window dialog, choose a name (for example, IIS), and set the TCP port (in the above example, 8080).

Now your Windows firewall will allow incoming HTTP packets to reach your server.

Comment: Hi kol......thank u for taking time to reply me...i have done this its working fine in my system .but in the host machine i will get an connection timed out error...

Comment: I see. Have you checked your Windows firewall settings on the server? I updated my answer.

Comment: hi.ya i have checked it...actually i am using port 80..is it fine...or should i use 8080 port...and port 80 is opened..when i enter just the ip in other system, i am not getting any response from that host system..it says the connection timed out...and the windows firewall is compeletly disabled...there is some symantec firewall installed in my system...and even that is disabled..

Comment: Port 80 is fine, I wrote 8080 only as an example. So you can ping the server from the client, but cannot open the website, in spite of that it can be opened on the server itself, and Windows firewall is turned off. How many network interfaces do you have on your client and server PCs? Only one, or more?

Comment: Type ipconfig in cmd window. Count the interfaces which have ip address. Do this on both the client and the server. For example, your client can easily have an active wifi connection in addition to a wired connection.

Comment: I just found this...
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Wireless Network Connection:

        Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : timeinc.com
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.150.36.201
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.150.36.1

Comment: OK, so you have only one interface. I guess these data are from the client. What about the server? Does it have only one interface too?

Comment: yes even it is of the same way.......i have another issue...actually i uninstalled my iis ...then again i reinstalled it...now i am not able find the default website directory inside the website directory...Do u have any idea...........

Comment: Oops. I would consider asking a separate question about this (but this time I suggest asking it on ServerFault instead of SO). Don't forget to mention that you use IIS 5.1 on Windows XP (this problem could be solved easily on e.g. Windows 2003 Server, but on XP it's more difficult because inetmgr doesn't help you).

Comment: Hmm, maybe not. I never had that problem, so I'm not sure it helps, but you could try the following: save all your stuff in C:\inetpub\www (Home.aspx etc.), delete C:\inetpub\www, uninstall IIS (Control Panel -> Add or Remove Programs -> Add/Remove Windows Components -> Uncheck IIS in the popup window -> follow steps), then reinstall IIS (use Add/Remove Windows Components again). This may recreate the default website. If yes, then copy back your files to C:\inetpub\www, and set the IP address, the TCP port etc. as previously.

Comment: its working fine now......i checked all those that u said me...but its still not working:(

Comment: Are your client and server in the same subnet? I check this for you if you send me the IP address and the subnet mask for both machines.

Comment: OK, so there is no network devices between the client and the server other than a hub/switch/router. You could ask the IT people about the settings of this device - if it's a router, there may be a rule which stops HTTP packets getting to the server.

Comment: I've just tested: our IT bans pinging machines; HTTP is enabled though. I strongly suggest consulting with the IT department. I think HTTP servers are not allowed in your LAN.

Comment: i am able to ping the machines with the ip address

Comment: System admin said that everything is working fine..He also said that the problem is with the OS..i am not getting any iis page when i just type the ip address in the host machine.Do you think the problem is with the OS..r do u have any other suggestion...

Comment: Can't you get someone with some IP networking knowledge? Your problem is much easier to solve on site...

Answer (score 0):

Is your application is running under "NETWORKSERVICE" Application Pool Identity.

Check IIS > Application Pools > select your application pool ur using > Advanced Setting..

> set Identity = NETWORKSERVICE ;

Comment: Hi vivek..thank u for replying...Actually i dint find any application pools tab i my iss 5.1......Can u tel me the procedure????